# jQuery client for REST webservice with jersey

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, client

I am new in jQuery and I'm trying to develop a client for my web service. I've tried something simple, just for testing, but still it doesn't work, although it seems ok to me.

I have the jQuery library in my tomee/webapp folder, along with my html and javascript files. If I write some non-jQuery code in my javascript file, it works.

I have the following code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="getAllButton" value="Get all books" onclick="return getAllBooks()"/>
        <div id="messageBox"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

client.js

```
function getAllBooks() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'application/xml',
        type: 'GET',
        url: rootURL + '/books',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(1);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(2);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that no alert will appear. If a write pure javascript (I mean without jQuery), alerts will do appear.

Why do alerts not appear? Any advice?

Thank you!

Sorin

Comment: please explain symptoms. Are errors thrown in browser console? Does either alert fire? There are a lot of variables troubleshooting AJAX, just providing code doesn't tell a lot

Comment: The problem is that no alert will appear.

Comment: that is not enough detail. You must look in browser console for script errors, and inspect the request itself to see if it is being made. Is page in same folder as scripts? If not, scripts aren't loading. Can see in Network tab of console if scripts are loading

Comment: thanks...I didn't know about how to debug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks charlietfl for your tips! They helped me solve the problem.

The problem was that it didn't know who rootURL is. I found rootURL in an example and I thought that is something defined in jQuery. It seems it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to find out what works and what not; try changing your client.js to:

```
alert(1); 
function getAllBooks() {
    alert(2);
    window.open(rootURL + '/books'); 
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'application/xml',
        type: 'GET',
        url: rootURL + '/books',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(3);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(4);
        }
    });
}
```

If you see the alert #1 (when your html page loads) then your client.js path is OK. If you see alert #2 (when you click the button) then at least the function is being called.

Verify if window.open() shows what your web service is supposed to show you (even a error message will guide you throw the right path). And of course, if you see alert #3 or #4 then your problem was mysteriously solved by it self.... it sometimes happens :-)

NOTE: If you know how to use the javascript console of your browser use console.log() instead of alert() for debugging;